# What does TypeError non_object_property_load mean?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I see this error a bunch in javascript that I'm debugging.  In the JS console Chrome says something very similar to

```
TypeError
    arguments: Array[2]
    message: "-"
    stack: "-"
    type: "non_object_property_load"
    __proto__: Error
```

I can usually work my way to the underlying problem, but in general what does the error represent?

Is there any way to get a stack trace to the line that caused the problem?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You're trying to access something from `null` or `undefined`.

For example, this code will throw such an error:

```
null.foo;
```

You should check which properties you're accessing from which objects, and use something like `obj && obj.prop` instead of just `obj.prop`.

---

You can get the stack trace using:

```
console.log(new Error().stack);
```

The `-` means the property is a getter, and is not displayed automatically because a getter can have side effects. The stack is available though (the `-` does *not* mean "not available"); you just have to access it explicitly.

Comment: In these cases why doesn't chrome display the stack trace like it does for other exceptions?

Comment: @Leopd: Are you evaluating through the console? It works fine for me if I execute it normally, e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/XNLJ4/.

Comment: Yeah, the simple cases like your fiddle always show the line number.  It also says "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'foo' of null" instead of the obscure message.  I only see "non_object_property_load" when I'm deep in complex code.  I wish I knew why the exception sometimes doesn't get properly caught and rendered.

Comment: Well thanks for explaining this part.  The mystery of why it sometimes doesn't throw an error properly deserves its own question.